# Three out of four ain't bad

Tags: connect-wall

The set of sixteen words below can be partitioned. Each partition is of four words that have something in common. I invite you to figure out the partitions and commonalities.

ACORN, ALI, BRADLEY, CLEAN, COUNTY, FIRE, HAM, HERSHEY, INNOCENT, IS, LEO, MAMET, MARTIN, RUN, URBAN, VERITE

Comment: there are four rot13(cbcrf)

Answer (score 23, accepted):

I believe the answer is:

Category #1:

> MILTON: ACORN, BRADLEY, HERSHEY, MAMET (people or fictional characters named Milton)

Category #2:

> POPE: INNOCENT, LEO, MARTIN, URBAN (popes)

Category #3:

> DRY: CLEAN, COUNTY, FIRE, RUN  (phrases like DRY _)

Category #4:

> DEN: ALI, HAM, IS, VERITE (proper names that start with DEN_)

The Commonality:

> Milton, Pope and Dryden were all 17th century English poets. We only get three, but three out of four ain't bad!